# Why is angular not displaying the result? Why is only the complete-handler invoked?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, rxjs

In case this helps - I've been setting up:

- An ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
- A .NET Core 8 backend for frontend
- An Angular SPA getting served inside the aforementiond bff using typescript (ES2022)

Flow for requests:

```
-> SPA (Cookie) -> BFF (Token) -> API
```

The SPA is the one giving me a headache, because I just can't get it display or interpret fetched data, although I'm basically copying (working) Microsoft code.

As for the fetched data - it's the default result of the `WeatherForecastController` seen here:

```
using ErpBridge.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ErpBridge.Server.WebApi.Controllers;

[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    public WeatherForecastController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

The SPA used the BFF's Proxy (OidcProxy from GitHub) to send requests there, the Angular component in `weather.component.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather',
  templateUrl: './weather.component.html',
  styleUrl: './weather.component.scss'
})
export class WeatherComponent {
    public forecasts: WeatherForecast[] = [];

    constructor(http: HttpClient) {

        http.get<WeatherForecast[]>('api/weatherforecast').subscribe(
            {
                next: (v) => this.forecasts = v,
                error: (e) => console.error(e),
                complete: () => console.info('complete')
            });
    }
}

interface WeatherForecast {
    date: string;
    temperatureC: number;
    temperatureF: number;
    summary: string;
}
```

The template in `weather.component.html` looks like this:

```
<p *ngIf="!forecasts?.length"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table class='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tableLabel" *ngIf="forecasts.length">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Temp. (C)</th>
        <th>Temp. (F)</th>
        <th>Summary</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let forecast of forecasts">
        <td>{{ forecast.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ forecast.temperatureC }}</td>
        <td>{{ forecast.temperatureF }}</td>
        <td>{{ forecast.summary }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have verified that the request to 'api/weatherforecast' is:

- getting sent
- is answered with HTTP 200 as well as the following result as taken out of Chromes DevTools:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2024-03-02",
        "temperatureC": 54,
        "temperatureF": 129,
        "summary": "Freezing"
    },
    {
        "date": "2024-03-03",
        "temperatureC": 5,
        "temperatureF": 40,
        "summary": "Freezing"
    } // redacted for brevity
]
```

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong handling either:

- the observable in the user-interface / html template of the component (the value 'v' of my request-handler contains an array of `WeatherForecast`)

Thanks in advance

I've tried various ways of handling the resulting JSON response from my API based on:

- The default Microsoft code
- Taken out of the Angular hero tutorial
- Samples of the OidcProxy AuthenticationGateway SPA
- Various methods of displaying the forecasts-member of my component although I'm pretty sure this variable is never being filled with the expected array

What I expected? To be honest - some kind of error-message pointing me in the right direction. Sadly I'm missing any...

To be honest - I'm pretty comfy in C# - but I'm a novice in Angular as well as in TS.

Comment: Move your code `http.get<WeatherForecast[]>()...` from `constructor` into `ngOnInit` method. Have you checked the `v` contains what value via `console.log(v)`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment - i edited my code as you've mentioned moving the request to ngOnInit and logging the value of 'v'. As for the console-output: it print's the expected array of WeatherForecast. Sadly - the user-interface is not showing anything about those forecasts.

Answer (score 0):

with a fresh day i revisited the angular docs.

I forgot to include my component to NgModule:declarations.

The code is working fine now...